# Getting “npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"” when attempting to install Angular CLI

Tags: node.js

I'm facing this error when I'm trying to install Angular CLI. Please help me with the issue:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"
```

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I have set registry via `npm config set registry <corporate_registry_url>` an authenticated via `npm login` and I had this 401 error until I've added to `.npmrc` config file this line

```
//<repo_url>:always-auth=true
```

after the following line

```
//<repo_url>:_authToken=<token>
```

This way, token got applied and installation of a package succeeded.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner right, I've made it a bit more visible

Answer (score 10):

I was trying to setup npm for the first time on my laptop. My corporate npm registry is in Artifactory. I had configured my auth through the .npmrc file by adding the below details to it (as suggested in Artifactory "set me up"):

```
_auth=xxxxxxxxxxxx
always-auth=true
email=xxxxxx@xxxx.com
```

The error `(npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm")` got resolved after removing underscore (`_`) from `auth` in the .npmrc file:

```
auth=xxxxxxxxxxxx
always-auth=true
email=xxxxxx@xxxx.com
```

Comment: This actually worked ! tried so many things but this is what actually worked ...Thanks !

Comment: Solution that actually worked! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: didn't work for me either

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you're running into authentication issues with your company's internal npm registry. I'd try one of these solutions:

- Talk with your DevOps team and figure out why your login isn't working. This is the type of thing that a company ought to document in a wiki or similar place.
- Try adding `--registry https://registry.npmjs.org` to your `npm` commands in the short term. This will install from the public registry, which you should not need to authenticate to.

If you run `npm config ls`, you will likely see a `registry` line. There should be a filename above it ending in `.npmrc`; if you edit this file you can change the registry to the public one. (Usually it's `~/.npmrc` but may depend on your configuration.)

Comment: Usually people use a local registry because their firewalls restrict access such that they can't connect the registry.npmjs.org. If that is the case, your suggestion won't work.

Answer (score 5):

Adding following in `.npmrc` worked for me:

```
_auth = <Basic_Authentication_Header>
email = myemail@email.com
always-auth = true
```

Online utility which can help to generate Basic Authentication Header can be found here - https://www.blitter.se/utils/basic-authentication-header-generator/

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked for me too. Had to add scope at the top as well:
`@jfrog:registry=https://yourcompany.registry.com/artifactory`
then running 
`npm install --scope=jfrog --save package-name`
worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me:

1. Ran

> npm config ls

Look for the location/path of where .npmrc - next to text: userconfig

2. Go to that location/path then delete the .nprmc file
3. Ran the in npm install command - e.g:

> npm install cypress --save-dev

Answer (score 2):

It helps if you post your NPM configs.  Use `npm config ls` to see what registry you have set up. I ran into a similar error message and my solution was to set the registry as secured HTTP: `registry=https://...`. I'm also using my job's Artifactory server. Once you set the registry, you can try authenticating against the Artifactory registry using `npm login`, which will prompt you for username, password, and the e-mail address associated with your Artifactory registry account.

This Artifactory endpoint will retrieve an encrypted auth token (which can be used for reaching the Artifactory API) and e-mail:

`curl -vv -<username>:<encrypted-password> http://<ARTIFACTORY-HOST</artifactory/api/npm/auth`

You can get `<encrypted-password>` usually by going to your Artifactory account in the browser at `https://<artifactory-host>/artifactory/webapp/#/profile`.

Sample output:

```
_auth = <encrypted-auth-token>
always-auth = true
email = joe.smith@somehost.com
```

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is :

I deleted the .npmrc file under C/users/ folder. and ran npx vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc command to create a new file in the users folder

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue because we recently integrated AWS CodeArtifact into our platform, and I forgot to run

`aws codeartifact login --tool npm --domain {MY_DOMAIN} --domain-owner {MY_AWS_ACCOUNT} --repository {MY_REPOSITORY}`

Which will overwrite your .npmrc file with proper authentication

Answer (score 0):

```
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -F
```

Is the only solution I found

Make sure to run `npm install -g vsts-npm-auth` before

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error.
the issue was the Password, I used '$' sign and made this error, I used another symbol and my problem was solved.